# Good way to a multi get of keys in couchbase with bucket of memcached type

Tags: memcached, couchbase

I have a couchbase bucket of memcached type. I want to bulk get keys from the bucket. N1QL will not work as it is of memcached type. What is a good way to do this? I want to avoid multiple calls since per request, I have to fetch for around 100 keys at a time and don't want to make so many connections at scale.

Comment: Which Couchbase SDK are you using (what programming language)?

Comment: Note that fetching 100 keys will be efficiently multiplexed over the SDK's KV connections - it won't create 100 connections.  Fetching in this way should be very efficient and can be done in parallel for performance.  It also avoids the N1QL parsing overhead.  If you know the keys, I would recommend KV getting in this way.

Comment: @dnault java sdk

Answer (score 2):

If you can, it would be best to migrate to an "Ephemeral" bucket which still runs in memory but can be replicated, rebalanced, indexed, etc.

Comment: Trying to avoid changing bucket configuration as this would affect others

Comment: FWIW, it "shouldn't" affect others.  The ephemeral bucket can be configured to have the same behaviour as a memcached bucket, and it adds much more functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As Graham Pople commented, if you know the document IDs, you can efficiently fetch many documents at once using the Couchbase Java SDK's Reactive API.

The documentation: [Batching using the Couchbase Java SDK's Reactive API](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/howtos/concurrent-async-apis.html#batching)

Here's a slightly modified version of the most general code example from that documentation:

```java
List<String> docsToFetch = List.of("doc1", "doc2", "doc3");
Map<String, Throwable> failedResults = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

List<GetResult> successfulResults = Flux.fromIterable(docsToFetch)
    .flatMap(key -> collection.reactive().get(key)
      .onErrorResume(e -> {
        failedResults.put(key, e);
        return Mono.empty();
      })
    )
    .collectList()
    .block();
}
```